# How to use the head tag efficiently?

Tags: html

which is best order to including css link and script tag in HTML and why ?
How to use the head tag efficiently  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document wont start to render(display on screen), until all resources in the head have loaded. Therefore, JavaScript files should be moved to the bottom of the page, unless it is necessary for them to run as soon as the page loads. Css should go in the head, and preferably be in just one file, as opposed to many files